# Typescript factory class and generic not working

Tags: typescript, generics, factory

Given the following code as an exemple:
I am trying to generate a factory class to serialize and deserialize my instances so I can save and read them from a database.

```
abstract class Brush {
    private _opacity: number;

    constructor(opacity: number) {
        this._opacity = opacity;
    }

    public get opacity(): number {
        return this._opacity;
    }
}

class SolidColorBrush extends Brush {
    private _color: string;

    constructor(
        opacity: number,
        color: string) {
        super(opacity);

        this._color = color as string;
    }

    public get color(): string {
        return this._color;
    }

    public static fromJSON(json: string): SolidColorBrush {
        const parsedJson: any = JSON.parse(json);

        const solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(
            parsedJson.opacity,
            parsedJson.color);

        return solidColorBrush;
    }

    public toJSON(): string {
        const json: string = JSON.stringify({
            opacity: this.opacity,
            color: this.color
        });

        return json;
    }
}

class GradientBrush extends Brush {
    private _color1: string;
    private _color2: string;

    constructor(
        opacity: number,
        color1: string,
        color2: string) {
        super(opacity);

        this._color1 = color1;
        this._color2 = color2;
    }

    public get color1(): string {
        return this._color1;
    }
    public get color2(): string {
        return this._color2;
    }

    public static fromJSON(json: string): GradientBrush {
        const parsedJson: any = JSON.parse(json);

        const gradientBrush = new GradientBrush(
            parsedJson.opacity,
            parsedJson.color1,
            parsedJson.color2);

        return gradientBrush;
    }

    public toJSON(): string {
        const json: string = JSON.stringify({
            opacity: this.opacity,
            color1: this.color1,
            color2: this.color2
        });

        return json;
    }
}

class BrushFactory {
    // this does not work
    public fromJson<T extends Brush>(
        t: new (...args: any[]) => T,
        json: string): T {
        switch (t) {
            case SolidColorBrush:
                return SolidColorBrush.fromJSON(json);
            case GradientBrush:
                return GradientBrush.fromJSON(json);
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }

    // this works
    public fromJson2(
        t: new (...args: any[]) => Brush,
        json: string): Brush {
        switch (t) {
            case SolidColorBrush:
                return SolidColorBrush.fromJSON(json);
            case GradientBrush:
                return GradientBrush.fromJSON(json);
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }

    // this does not work
    public toJson<T extends Brush>(
        t: new (...args: any[]) => T,
        brush: T): string {
        switch (t) {
            case SolidColorBrush:
                return (brush as SolidColorBrush).toJSON();
            case GradientBrush:
                return (brush as GradientBrush).toJSON();
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }

    // this works
    public toJson2(
        t: new (...args: any[]) => Brush,
        brush: Brush): string {
        switch (t) {
            case SolidColorBrush:
                return (brush as SolidColorBrush).toJSON();
            case GradientBrush:
                return (brush as GradientBrush).toJSON();
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does toJSON not compile and toJSON2 compile?
Same thing for fromJSON and fromJSON2.

I'd prefer to use generics here in this case for my factory pattern.
It's much easier to consume and less error prone since IMO.
Any work around would be appreciated?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: [ts]
Type 'typeof SolidColorBrush' is not comparable to type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.
  Type 'SolidColorBrush' is not comparable to type 'T'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re `fromJSON` errors: Testing that `t` equals one of your classes does not automatically change the type of `T`.  That would be a feature similar to [this open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).

Re `toJSON` errors: It's unfortunate in this case that TypeScript does not consider `T` and a `Brush` subclass to be comparable.  See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17445) for more information.

Re how to write the code: I don't see what `BrushFactory.fromJson` is buying you compared to calling `fromJSON` directly on the `Brush` subclass, since you have to have the subclass anyway to pass into `BrushFactory.fromJson`.  Likewise, if you declare `toJSON` as an abstract method on the `Brush` class, then you can call it on any `Brush` and there is no need for `BrushFactory.toJson`.